# ¿Que expresión regular se usa para denegar letras en un campo input de solo números?

Tags: javascript

hola que tal alguien me podría apoyar tengo un input de tipo text el cual solo quiero permitir el uso de números enteros y decimales ya que es para datos como litros, kilometros, precios etc. Pero no se que expresion regular poner o como formarla.

Tengo este código que hice para realizar a  la inversa me deniega el uso de números en campos de solo letras que pudiera cambiar ?

```
const validar = function(campo) {
  let valor = campo.value;  
  // Verifica si el valor del campo (input) contiene numeros.
  if(/\d/.test(valor)) { 
  //Remueve los numeros que contiene el valor y lo establece en el valor del campo (input).
  campo.value = valor.replace(/\d/g,'');
  }

};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías usar esta expresión regular `/^\d*\.?\d*$/` para los números decimales:

```
const validar = function(campo) {
  let valor = campo.value;  
  // Verifica si el valor del campo (input) contiene numeros.
  if(/^\d*\.?\d*$/.test(valor)) { 
  // Remueve los numeros que contiene el valor y lo establece en el valor del campo (input).
  }
};
```

Pero si también querés que no te deje tipear el resto que no sea número podrías hacer que en el evento `keyup` utilizando el `keyCode` para obtener la tecla, chequee si no es un número y no lo escriba. Para mi, esta opción es la mejor para escribir sólo dígitos:

```js
var texto = document.querySelector('#texto');

texto.addEventListener('keypress', function(e) {
  // keyCode del punto decimal, también se puede cambiar por la coma que sería el 44
  const decimalCode = 46;
  // chequeo que el keyCode corresponda a las teclas de los números y al punto decimal
  if ((e.keyCode < 48 || e.keyCode > 57) && e.keyCode != decimalCode) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
  // chequeo que sólo exista un punto decimal
  else if (e.keyCode == decimalCode && /\./.test(this.value)) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
}, true)
```

```html
<input type="text" name="texto" id="texto" />
```

Comment: muchas gracias si funciono , era justo lo que necesitaba , solo una pregunta en esta parte: var texto = document.querySelector('#texto'); aquí va el id de mi input para poner mas id´s se concatenan ahí?, o declaro mas variables, o como puedo usar esa función para otros inputs?

Comment: Dos opciones, la más fácil sería usar jQuery y llamar con el selector a todos tus elementos que necesiten usar el tipo de input numérico y luego agregar el evento con ese selector. La otra, es reutilizar esto, sacar la función del keyup por fuera, ponerle un nombre y llamarlo para todos los selectores dentro de un ciclo.

Comment: una disculpa no me queda muy claro esto: llamar con el selector a todos tus elementos , osea crear un tipo array que me guarde en una variable mis id y luego pasar esa variable al evento addEventListener ?

Comment: Te dejo este [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9nopxzjs/) para que visualices las dos opciones que te digo.

Comment: excelente ya comprendí a que te referías muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Acá te comparto un código que puedes utilizar para poder validar el contenido del campo de texto, evaluando cada vez que se edita el input si el valor es numérico o decimal o no.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $(document).on('keyup', '#camponumerico', function(){
    var regexp = /^\d+(\.\d{1,9})?$/;
    var value = $(this).val()
    if(regexp.test(value)){
      console.log('numerico o decimal');
    } else {
      console.log('no numerico');
    }
  });

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="camponumerico" id="camponumerico">
```

Espero te pueda servir.

Answer (score 0):

Lo importante es el regex, hay varios a lo largo de la red. Uno que permite hasta dos decimales con números negativos y separador decimal '.' ó ',' es el siguiente:

```
regex = /^-?\d*[.,]?\d{0,2}$/;    

function setFiltroDecimales(element, valorInicial) {

    if(valorInicial)
        element.value = valorInicial;

    ["input", "keydown", "keyup", "mousedown", "mouseup", "select", "contextmenu", "drop"].forEach(
        function(event) {
            element.addEventListener(
                event, 
                function() {

                    let esValido = regex.test(element.value)

                    // Realiza las acciones dependiendo de si se validaron o no 
                    if (esValido) 
                    {
                       elemento.oldValue = elemento.value;
                       elemento.oldSelectionStart = elemento.selectionStart;
                       elemento.oldSelectionEnd = elemento.selectionEnd;
                    } else if (elemento.hasOwnProperty("oldValue")) {
                       elemento.value = elemento.oldValue;
                       elemento.setSelectionRange(elemento.oldSelectionStart, elemento.oldSelectionEnd);
                    }
                }
            );
        }
    );
}

setFiltroDecimales(document.getElementById("tuIdDelInput"), 0);
```